# Flutter android app is crashing with firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, crash, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, crashlytics-android

I am using `flutter` and `firebase_messaging` in my app. When I run my app locally, everything is running properly both in the **emulator** and **real device**. However, if I build (`flutter build apk -debug`) the app and run the same in a **real device** or **browserstack** then the app is crashing. I am not able to understand the log as well. Please help me to understand the issue from the below log and fix it.

```
01-06 22:02:55.560 D/AndroidRuntime(14787): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-06 22:02:55.564 D/AndroidRuntime(14787): CheckJNI is OFF
01-06 22:02:55.619 D/ICU     (14787): No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-06 22:02:55.646 I/Radio-JNI(14787): register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-06 22:02:55.656 D/AndroidRuntime(14787): Calling main entry com.android.commands.input.Input
01-06 22:02:55.656 I/Input   (14787): injectKeyEvent: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_HOME, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=31784765, downTime=31784765, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
01-06 22:02:55.661 I/Input   (14787): injectKeyEvent: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_HOME, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=31784765, downTime=31784765, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
01-06 22:02:55.668 I/ActivityManager(  923): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL (has extras)} from uid 1000 on display 0
01-06 22:02:55.677 D/AndroidRuntime(14787): Shutting down VM
01-06 22:02:55.679 W/SearchService(11689): Abort, client detached.
01-06 22:02:55.680 I/GEL     (30394): handleIntent(Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL (has extras) })
01-06 22:02:55.685 I/MicroDetector(11689): Keeping mic open: false
01-06 22:02:55.685 I/MicrophoneInputStream(11689): mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ah@8859f3f
01-06 22:02:55.686 E/AudioRecord-JNI(11689): Error -4 during AudioRecord native read
01-06 22:02:55.686 I/DeviceStateChecker(11689): DeviceStateChecker cancelled
01-06 22:02:55.756 D/sound_trigger_platform(  556): platform_stdev_check_and_update_concurrency: concurrency active 0, tx 0, rx 0, concurrency session_allowed 1
01-06 22:02:55.757 I/SoundTriggerHwService::Module(  556): void android::SoundTriggerHwService::Module::onCallbackEvent(const sp<android::SoundTriggerHwService::CallbackEvent> &) mClient == 0
01-06 22:02:55.759 I/MicroRecognitionRunner(11689): Stopping hotword detection.
01-06 22:02:55.759 I/MicroRecognitionRunner(11689): Detection finished
01-06 22:02:55.775 I/MicroDetectionWorker(11689): Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
01-06 22:02:55.804 I/MicroRecognitionRunner(11689): Starting detection.
01-06 22:02:55.807 I/AudioFlinger(  556): AudioFlinger's thread 0xf2783340 ready to run
01-06 22:02:55.812 I/SoundTriggerHwService::Module(  556): void android::SoundTriggerHwService::Module::onCallbackEvent(const sp<android::SoundTriggerHwService::CallbackEvent> &) mClient == 0
01-06 22:02:55.815 I/MicrophoneInputStream(11689): mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ah@b14a343
01-06 22:02:55.825 E/audio_route(  556): unable to find path 'set-capture-format-default'
01-06 22:02:55.825 D/sound_trigger_platform(  556): platform_stdev_check_and_update_concurrency: concurrency active 0, tx 1, rx 0, concurrency session_allowed 0
01-06 22:02:55.881 D/MultiDexClassLoader(14232): notifyColdstartDone
01-06 22:02:55.906 I/MicroDetectionWorker(11689): onReady
01-06 22:02:55.952 W/Bg_Shared2(14870): type=1400 audit(0.0:19111): avc: granted { read } for name="boot_id" dev="proc" ino=2271116 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file
01-06 22:02:55.952 W/Bg_Shared2(14870): type=1400 audit(0.0:19112): avc: granted { read open } for path="/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id" dev="proc" ino=2271116 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file
01-06 22:02:55.952 W/Bg_Shared2(14870): type=1400 audit(0.0:19113): avc: granted { getattr } for path="/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id" dev="proc" ino=2271116 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file
01-06 22:02:55.955 W/Bg_Shared2(14870): type=1400 audit(0.0:19114): avc: granted { getattr } for path="/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id" dev="proc" ino=2271116 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file
01-06 22:02:56.035 D/SoLoader(14232): About to load: libiopri-jni.so
01-06 22:02:56.035 D/SoLoader(14232): libiopri-jni.so found on /data/data/com.facebook.katana/lib-xzs
01-06 22:02:56.041 D/SoLoader(14232): Loading lib dependencies: [liblowlevel.so, libshadowmalloc.so, libforce_dlopen.so, libdistract.so, libdextricks.so, liblog.so, libgnustl_shared.so, libdl.so, libc.so]
01-06 22:02:56.043 D/SoLoader(14232): Loaded: libiopri-jni.so
01-06 22:02:56.043 D/IoPriLoader(14232): load success: true
01-06 22:02:56.051 D/VpsController(14232): Binding to exo service
01-06 22:02:56.063 D/SoLoader(14232): About to merge: mobileconfig-jni / libcoldstart.so
01-06 22:02:56.086 D/SoLoader(14232): About to merge: xanalyticsnative-jni / libcoldstart.so
01-06 22:02:56.224 I/mobileconfig(14232): Params map streaming - readbytes: 605644/605644
01-06 22:02:56.224 I/mobileconfig(14232): Successfully parsed params_map.txt
01-06 22:02:56.269 D/AndroidRuntime(14841): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-06 22:02:56.272 D/AndroidRuntime(14841): CheckJNI is OFF
01-06 22:02:56.321 D/ICU     (14841): No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-06 22:02:56.335 I/mobileconfig(14232): Initialized MobileConfig - directory: /data/user/0/com.facebook.katana/files, deviceId: a38e0bf7-9c66-4b08-9d51-7c6ff11588bf, appVersion: 175.0.0.40.97, session: , paramHash: bd88cdb3b7d9e09ae2bd9bf0fc254386, urlParams: [locale=en_US,client_country_code=US,access_token=350685531728|62f8ce9f74b12f84c123cc23437a4a32], readOnly: false
01-06 22:02:56.351 I/Radio-JNI(14841): register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-06 22:02:56.364 D/AndroidRuntime(14841): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-06 22:02:56.369 I/ActivityManager(  923): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.personal.testapp/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0
01-06 22:02:56.381 D/AndroidRuntime(14841): Shutting down VM
01-06 22:02:56.391 W/SearchService(11689): Abort, client detached.
01-06 22:02:56.396 I/MicroDetector(11689): Keeping mic open: false
01-06 22:02:56.396 I/DeviceStateChecker(11689): DeviceStateChecker cancelled
01-06 22:02:56.396 I/MicrophoneInputStream(11689): mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ah@b14a343
01-06 22:02:56.397 E/AudioRecord-JNI(11689): Error -4 during AudioRecord native read
01-06 22:02:56.402 I/main    (14935): type=1400 audit(0.0:19115): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:wifi_log_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1160 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
01-06 22:02:56.402 I/main    (14935): type=1400 audit(0.0:19116): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:log_tag_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1161 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
01-06 22:02:56.402 I/main    (14935): type=1400 audit(0.0:19117): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:log_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1162 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
01-06 22:02:56.409 I/ActivityManager(  923): Start proc 14935:com.personal.testapp/u0a101 for activity com.personal.testapp/.MainActivity
01-06 22:02:56.466 I/SoundTriggerHwService::Module(  556): void android::SoundTriggerHwService::Module::onCallbackEvent(const sp<android::SoundTriggerHwService::CallbackEvent> &) mClient == 0
01-06 22:02:56.468 I/MicroRecognitionRunner(11689): Stopping hotword detection.
01-06 22:02:56.468 I/MicroRecognitionRunner(11689): Detection finished
01-06 22:02:56.486 D/FirebaseApp(14935): com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
01-06 22:02:56.487 D/FirebaseApp(14935): com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
01-06 22:02:56.490 D/FirebaseApp(14935): com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement is not linked. Skipping initialization.
01-06 22:02:56.490 I/FirebaseInitProvider(14935): FirebaseApp initialization successful
01-06 22:02:56.511 F/flutter (14935): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/library_loader.cc(24)] Check failed: result.
01-06 22:02:56.512 F/libc    (14935): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 14935 (personal.testapp)
01-06 22:02:56.512 I/debuggerd(  373): type=1400 audit(0.0:19118): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:log_tag_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1161 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
01-06 22:02:56.512 I/debuggerd(  373): type=1400 audit(0.0:19119): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:log_tag_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1161 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
01-06 22:02:56.512 I/debuggerd(  373): type=1400 audit(0.0:19120): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:log_tag_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=1161 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:unlabeled:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
01-06 22:02:56.515 W/        (  373): debuggerd: handling request: pid=14935 uid=10101 gid=10101 tid=14935
01-06 22:02:56.664 F/DEBUG   (14964): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-06 22:02:56.664 F/DEBUG   (14964): Build fingerprint: 'google/angler/angler:7.0/NRD90T/3154927:user/release-keys'
01-06 22:02:56.664 F/DEBUG   (14964): Revision: '0'
01-06 22:02:56.664 F/DEBUG   (14964): ABI: 'arm'
01-06 22:02:56.664 F/DEBUG   (14964): pid: 14935, tid: 14935, name: personal.testapp  >>> com.personal.testapp <<<
01-06 22:02:56.664 F/DEBUG   (14964): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-06 22:02:56.670 F/DEBUG   (14964): Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/library_loader.cc(24)] Check failed: result. 
01-06 22:02:56.670 F/DEBUG   (14964): '
01-06 22:02:56.671 F/DEBUG   (14964):     r0 00000000  r1 00003a57  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
01-06 22:02:56.671 F/DEBUG   (14964):     r8 00100019  r9 ffcc1d84  sl f21b20c0  fp ffcc1d18
01-06 22:02:56.671 F/DEBUG   (14964):     ip 00000058  sp ffcc1b30  lr f35ba537  pc f35bcd94  cpsr 200f0010
01-06 22:02:56.689 D/GcOptimizer(14232): Configure for next cold start: disable
01-06 22:02:56.715 W/BroadcastQueue(  923): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{9ec091b u0 ReceiverList{176072a 14232 com.facebook.katana/10096/u0 remote:1f60815}}
01-06 22:02:56.715 W/BroadcastQueue(  923): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.INET_CONDITION_ACTION flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{9ec091b u0 ReceiverList{176072a 14232 com.facebook.katana/10096/u0 remote:1f60815}}
01-06 22:02:56.737 W/fb4a.ServiceInfoParser(14232): X.447: Service com.facebook.analytics2.logger.LollipopUploadService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
01-06 22:02:56.737 W/fb4a.ServiceInfoParser(14232): X.447: Service com.facebook.backgroundlocation.reporting.periodic.PeriodicSignalCollectorJobService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
01-06 22:02:56.754 W/fb4a.ServiceInfoParser(14232): X.447: Service com.facebook.push.fbpushdata.FbPushDataHandlerService is missing meta key com.facebook.common.jobscheduler.compat.jobIds
01-06 22:02:56.780 W/BroadcastQueue(  923): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires com.facebook.permission.prod.FB_APP_COMMUNICATION due to registered receiver BroadcastFilter{40024cd u0 ReceiverList{735a64 14232 com.facebook.katana/10096/u0 remote:8381bf7}}
01-06 22:02:56.873 W/fb4a.0JA(14232): Called user scoped provider with no viewer. ViewerContextManager was created with no ViewerContext. Using EmptyViewerContextManager to return fake logged in instance.
01-06 22:02:56.918 W/fb4a.0JA(14232): Called user scoped provider with no viewer. ViewerContextManager was created with no ViewerContext. Using EmptyViewerContextManager to return fake logged in instance.
01-06 22:02:56.929 W/fb4a.0JA(14232): Called user scoped provider with no viewer. ViewerContextManager was created with no ViewerContext. Using EmptyViewerContextManager to return fake logged in instance.
01-06 22:02:56.947 D/AndroidRuntime(14967): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-06 22:02:56.953 D/AndroidRuntime(14967): CheckJNI is OFF
01-06 22:02:56.979 W/fb4a.0JA(14232): Called user scoped provider with no viewer. ViewerContextManager was created with no ViewerContext. Using EmptyViewerContextManager to return fake logged in instance.
01-06 22:02:56.997 D/ICU     (14967): No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-06 22:02:57.027 I/Radio-JNI(14967): register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-06 22:02:57.036 D/AndroidRuntime(14967): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-06 22:02:57.043 D/AndroidRuntime(14967): Shutting down VM
01-06 22:02:57.236 F/DEBUG   (14964): 
01-06 22:02:57.236 F/DEBUG   (14964): backtrace:
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #00 pc 00049d94  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #01 pc 00047533  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #02 pc 0001d885  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #03 pc 000193d1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #04 pc 00017014  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #05 pc 00155027  /data/app/com.personal.testapp-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0x119000)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #06 pc 0014a997  /data/app/com.personal.testapp-1/lib/arm/libflutter.so (offset 0x119000) (JNI_OnLoad+342)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #07 pc 002392f9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt17LoadNativeLibraryEP7_JNIEnvRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEEP8_jobjectP8_jstringPS9_+1844)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #08 pc 00003167  /system/lib/libopenjdkjvm.so (JVM_NativeLoad+178)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #09 pc 005de18d  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x56d000) (java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad+144)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #10 pc 005dddcd  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x56d000) (java.lang.Runtime.doLoad+136)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #11 pc 005df2b1  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x56d000) (java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0+540)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #12 pc 005f266b  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x56d000) (java.lang.System.loadLibrary+78)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #13 pc 000a8f41  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #14 pc 004015b9  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+228)
01-06 22:02:57.237 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #15 pc 000b01ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+178)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #16 pc 001eabc1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+200)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #17 pc 001e5171  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+492)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #18 pc 003fa0d1  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+236)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #19 pc 0009bf14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #20 pc 001c8fbb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #21 pc 001cdb23  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+114)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #22 pc 001e5157  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+466)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #23 pc 003fa0d1  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+236)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #24 pc 0009bf14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #25 pc 001c8fbb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #26 pc 001cda8d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+92)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #27 pc 003f09ef  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+706)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #28 pc 000ad993  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+34)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #29 pc 000a8f41  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #30 pc 004015b9  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+228)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #31 pc 000b01ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+178)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #32 pc 001eabc1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+200)
01-06 22:02:57.238 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #33 pc 001e5171  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+492)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #34 pc 003fa0d1  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+236)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #35 pc 0009bf14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #36 pc 001c8fbb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #37 pc 001cda8d  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+92)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #38 pc 003f09ef  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+706)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #39 pc 000ad993  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+34)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #40 pc 01636aad  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate+40)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #41 pc 015bcfb1  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication+4508)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #42 pc 015b6af5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2+48)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #43 pc 015b4231  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage+3972)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #44 pc 015b1b73  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+110)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #45 pc 01b4ba55  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (android.os.Looper.loop+696)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #46 pc 015c2ce7  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+426)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #47 pc 000a8f41  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #48 pc 004015b9  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+228)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #49 pc 000b01ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+178)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #50 pc 00312671  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+56)
01-06 22:02:57.239 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #51 pc 00313a03  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12InvokeMethodERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectS4_S4_j+766)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #52 pc 002bae89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Method_invokeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_S3_+40)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #53 pc 00603f39  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (offset 0x56d000) (java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke+116)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #54 pc 02031b39  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+100)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #55 pc 020329b5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x153f000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1216)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #56 pc 000a8f41  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #57 pc 004015b9  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+228)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #58 pc 000b01ff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+178)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #59 pc 00312671  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+56)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #60 pc 00312483  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+266)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #61 pc 002757e3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+426)
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #62 pc 00063649  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
01-06 22:02:57.240 F/DEBUG   (14964):     #63 pc 00064f1b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+498)
01-06 22:02:57.302 D/SoLoader(14232): About to merge: profilo_network / libcoldstart.so
01-06 22:02:57.485 D/AndroidRuntime(14988): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-06 22:02:57.488 D/AndroidRuntime(14988): CheckJNI is OFF
01-06 22:02:57.534 D/ICU     (14988): No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-06 22:02:57.556 I/Radio-JNI(14988): register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-06 22:02:57.573 D/AndroidRuntime(14988): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-06 22:02:57.579 D/AndroidRuntime(14988): Shutting down VM
01-06 22:02:57.773 W/ActivityManager(  923):   Force finishing activity com.personal.testapp/.MainActivity
01-06 22:02:57.776 W/        (  373): debuggerd: resuming target 14935
01-06 22:02:57.778 I/BootReceiver(  923): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_00 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
01-06 22:02:57.803 I/ActivityManager(  923): Process com.personal.testapp (pid 14935) has died
01-06 22:02:57.803 I/Zygote  (  554): Process 14935 exited due to signal (6)
01-06 22:02:57.806 I/WindowManager(  923): Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.personal.testapp) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2305 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2300 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193
01-06 22:02:57.865 I/OpenGLRenderer(  923): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-06 22:02:57.865 D/OpenGLRenderer(  923): Swap behavior 1
01-06 22:02:57.871 I/MicroDetectionWorker(11689): Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
01-06 22:02:57.874 W/InputMethodManagerService(  923): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@d765ca7 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@ef90ce8
```

Comment: Did you try with the release APK? I think the release one is ok.

Comment: I tried with debug apk. Since release apk is also crashing and having enough stack trace.